# Problem running odoo-bin on MacOS (ValueError: current limit exceeds maximum limit)

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

I am unable to get Odoo 14 running on my MacOS machine. Some research into the following error suggests that I can manually configure the memory limits which may resolve the issue but I cannot find the relevant config files on my machine.

I've checked and reinstalled all of the requirements and I can't find much information to point me in the right direction.

```
(venv) kilgow@wmbp odoo-dev % python3 odoo/odoo-bin
2021-09-18 15:56:53,295 1931 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 14.0 
2021-09-18 15:56:53,295 1931 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/Users/kilgow/Desktop/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/addons', '/Users/kilgow/Library/Application Support/Odoo/addons/14.0', '/Users/kilgow/Desktop/odoo-dev/odoo/addons'] 
2021-09-18 15:56:53,295 1931 INFO ? odoo: database: default@default:default 
2021-09-18 15:56:53,351 1931 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kilgow/Desktop/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo-bin", line 8, in <module>
    odoo.cli.main()
  File "/Users/kilgow/Desktop/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/cli/command.py", line 61, in main
    o.run(args)
  File "/Users/kilgow/Desktop/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/cli/server.py", line 178, in run
    main(args)
  File "/Users/kilgow/Desktop/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/cli/server.py", line 172, in main
    rc = odoo.service.server.start(preload=preload, stop=stop)
  File "/Users/kilgow/Desktop/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 1298, in start
    rc = server.run(preload, stop)
  File "/Users/kilgow/Desktop/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 510, in run
    self.start(stop=stop)
  File "/Users/kilgow/Desktop/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 452, in start
    set_limit_memory_hard()
  File "/Users/kilgow/Desktop/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 83, in set_limit_memory_hard
    resource.setrlimit(rlimit, (config['limit_memory_hard'], hard))
ValueError: current limit exceeds maximum limit
(venv) kilgow@wmbp odoo-dev % python3 odoo/odoo-bin
```

Answer (score 7):

You should check out this [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/setup/deploy.html#id5) for more info, so the easy way is add an extra argument to your run script like below.

```
python3 odoo-bin --addons-path=addons -d mydb --limit-memory-hard 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Add these two lines to your `odoo.conf` file:

```
limit_memory_hard = 0
limit_memory_soft = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this could be due to the machine using an M1 chip. Manually increasing the memory limits did not resolve the problem.

I’ve managed to work around the issue by running Odoo and Postgres in Docker containers instead.

Comment: I had the same problem with Intel chip. Removing memory limits by setting them to 0 resolved the problem